# SqlPackage Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage

When I attempt to deploy **DACPACs** via **SqlPackage.exe**,
I encounter the error below :

```
An unexpected failure occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ReverseEngineerPopulators.Sql90TableBaseColumnPopulator`1.InsertElementIntoParent(SqlColumn element, TElement parent, ReverseEngineerOption option)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ReverseEngineerPopulators.ChildModelElementPopulator`2.CreateChildElement(TParent parent, EventArgs e, ReverseEngineerOption option)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ReverseEngineerPopulators.ChildModelElementPopulator`2.PopulateAllChildrenFromCache(IDictionary`2 cache, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, OrdinalSqlDataReader reader, ReverseEngineerOption option)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ReverseEngineerPopulators.TopLevelElementPopulator`1.Populate(SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, OrdinalSqlDataReader reader, ReverseEngineerOption option)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.ExecutePopulators(ReliableSqlConnection conn, IList`1 populators, Int32 totalPopulatorsCount, Int32 startIndex, Boolean progressAlreadyUpdated, ReverseEngineerOption option, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.ExecutePopulatorsInPass(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, ReverseEngineerOption option, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, Int32 totalCount, Tuple`2[] populatorsArray)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.PopulateBatch(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, SqlSchemaModel model, ReverseEngineerOption option, ErrorManager errorManager, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, SqlImportScope importScope)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineer.PopulateAll(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, ReverseEngineerOption option, ErrorManager errorManager, Boolean filterManagementScopedElements, SqlImportScope importScope, Boolean optimizeForQuery, ModelStorageType modelType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.ImportDatabase(SqlReverseEngineerConstructor constructor, DeploymentEngineContext context, ErrorManager errorManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnLoad(ErrorManager errors, DeploymentEngineContext context)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.PrepareModels()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.InitializePlanGeneratator()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.<>c__DisplayClass21.<CreateDeploymentArtifactGenerationOperation>b__1f(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.GenerateDeployScript(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.<>c__DisplayClasse.<DoDeployAction>b__4(DacServices service)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.ExecuteDeployOperation(String connectionString, String filePath, MessageWrapper messageWrapper, Boolean sourceIsPackage, Boolean targetIsPackage, Func`1 generateScriptFromPackage, Func`2 generateScriptFromDatabase)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.DoDeployAction(DeployArguments parsedArgs, Action`1 writeError, Action`2 writeMessage, Action`1 writeWarning)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.DoDeployActions(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Below is the *command I run*:

```
SET vardeploy2=/Action:Script
set varBlockOnDriftParameter=/p:BlockWhenDriftDetected=False 

"SSDTBinaries\SqlPackage.exe" %vardeploy2% %varBlockOnDriftParameter% /SourceFile:"dacpacs\DBName.dacpac" /Profile:"Profiles\%1.DBName.Publish.xml" >> Log.txt 2>>&1
```

I deploy to a **SQL Server 2008 R2**. The **SqlPackage.exe version** is **11.0.2820.0**.

The issue is intermittent, which suggests it's not related to the DACPAC being deployed or the destination database's schema. My best guess is that something about the **state of the database** is causing the problem.

Still, I haven't been able to identify anything unusual at the time of the failures.

When recreating the issue locally, using schema locks results in a different error message.

Has anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a more resent SQL Server Data Tools.